# Can the internal IP addresses of azure worker role instances be swapped?

Tags: networking, azure, azure-worker-roles

Like if one is on 192.168.1.1 and the other on 192.168.1.2, can you configure the machine's to each other's static IP addresses and thereby have them start receiving information for each other's InstanceInputEndpoints (since now the Azure gateway should route the InstanceInputEndpoint to the new owner of the IP address)?

Comment: Do you mean you have to do that when doing "VIP swap" operation?

Comment: No, I do not mean VIP swap. I mean reconfiguring the 'private' IP addresses that are not accessible to the rest of the world outside the hosted service. Hence the example IP addresses are from the 'private network' ip address range.

Comment: I see. Well, I don't *know", but my guess is this is impossible and is configured by the infrastructure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't do that!

And, as of today (Dec. 2013) you are highly advised to **never** set static IP Address of your Virtual Machine inside Windows Azure! You should **always** use default DHCP configuration. If you wand IP Address predictability check out [this blog post](http://blogs.staykov.net/2013/05/active-directory-in-azure-step-by-step.html). You can still use Azure Virtual Network with Web and Worker Roles and have IP Address predictability.

Answer (score 0):

If you use VM you should create several VM and a Networks, define address space you will use. When you create a VM, make sure your VM is using the networks that you create. If you forget to include the vm into the network, you need to recreate the VM.

Example how to change the internal IP using 3 VM:
Server A is connected to the network and get ip 192.168.0.1
Server B 192.168.0.2
Server C 192.168.0.3

shutdown all your server from azure portal so that the status is deallocated then turn it on with this sequence:
Server B
Server C
Server A

The Result will be:
Server A 192.168.0.3
Server B 192.168.0.1
Server C 192.168.0.2

If you turn off the VM from inside the VM, it won't be change the internal IP.

Answer (score -1):

If you remote onto one of your VMs, you will see an XML file at

```
C:\config
```

The filename looks something like

```
[deployment id]_[role name]_[instance number].[version number]
```

Inside the file you will find all the instances in the deployment with their IP addresses. If you edit the IP address in this file for a particular role instance on a particular VM, that VM will think that the IP address for the instance is the one in the file and will start routing traffic to it.

*Warning: I've never tried to do this programmatically. Also, the changes will get wiped out if there is any update to the deployment (either initiated by you or by Azure). And there might be some other horrible side effect.*

Comment: you should NEVER EVER edit this file, if you want a stable deployment!

Comment: I'm not disagreeing, but out of interest, why do you say that? do you have a link explaining what problems it would cause?

Comment: first of all, because what you describe is very unlikely to happen. Traffic is distributed from the Windows Azure Load Balancer. You can never skip that, even with InstanceInput Endpoint. And IP Addresses are allocated via DHCP. This file, my speculation, only serves to initilize the RoleEnvironment static class - to populate the role instances, endpoints etc, which you can access through code. So if you edit this file, the best result would be to cheat your code, but the Azure Load Balancer or internal traffic. The worst - will cause a role recycle and fresh copy of the file.